# How might you grab information from a page that only populates AFTER that page executes javascript? (C#)

Tags: c#, javascript

Hey there.  I have a CE program which needs to get information from a website.  I can't simply grab the source code, because the information is only displayed after the page's javascript is executed.  Is there a way to view a page's information/source/links after javascript has fully load the information?  Thanks!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure thing, [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Linked is the jQuery wrapper for it, which hides all the annoyances of getting it right in a cross-browser way.

The basic idea of AJAX is, you make a call from javascript and end your function. When the result eventually comes, a function handler is called where you can update your page with the result (or failure message, depending on the case).

You probably need a middle-man on your server that reads the remote web site and gives it back to your page in JSON, the format AJAX is made to work with, otherwise your browser will most likely deny the request if the page you want to read is on another domain.

Answer (score 0):

Hey - I think that will be difficult since values set by javascripts are notoriously client side information that will only be accessible to the application (server side) when the form is posted back to the server. But you should be able to make the javascripts set values that are inside an updatepanel and fired back to the server using standard asp.net ajax controls. This does however seem a bit too complicated for most scenarios.